# Ansible parted command fails when new disk "being used"

Tags: azure, ansible, rhel

Using Ansible v2.10.4 to configure RHEL 8 VMs on Azure IaaS, and am trying to use the *parted* directive to partition a new data disk:

```
- name: Partition the data disk for app use.
  parted:
    device: /dev/sdc
    number: 1
    state: present
    align: optimal
    label: msdos
    part_start: 0%
    part_end: 100%
    part_type: primary
```

This generally works about half the time; when it doesn't, it fails with this message:

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "err": "Error: Partition(s) on /dev/sdc are being used.\n", "msg": "Error while running parted script: /sbin/parted -s -m -a optimal /dev/sdc -- unit KiB mklabel msdos mkpart primary 0% 100%", "out": "", "rc": 1}
```

While I'm not sure why a newly created, unpartitioned/unformatted disk would be "in use", I added this directive above it to remove any partitions:

```
- name: First ensure the data disk is "de-partitioned" (so next call to parted doesn't fail).
  parted:
    device: /dev/sdc
    number: 1
    state: absent
```

Sometimes this works, but other times, it also fails with a slightly different (but effectively the same) message:

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "err": "Warning: Partition /dev/sdc1 is being used. Are you sure you want to continue?\n", "msg": "Error while running parted script: /sbin/parted -s -m -a optimal /dev/sdc -- rm 1", "out": "", "rc": 1}
```

Is there any way with Ansible to test whether a disk is "in use" before attempting to do anything with it?

Comment: (a) I would guess consult the `ansible_mounts` facts, or the output of `mount` to see where those partitions are mounted (b) have you run `parted --list` to examine the state of affairs? no one on SO can _guess_ what's going on with your system, even if it was in fact a programming question

Answer (score 0):

Found out that when the RHEL system boots, there's no guarantee that the second disk will be the /dev/sdc device; uncovered that when it fails, it was allocated as /dev/sdb).  So having to work through determining the device name at the time I need to access it.

Comment: in AWS, the EBS volumes show up under `/dev/disk/by-label/` with `vol-` in the name, so there may be something similar with Azure disks